# Sort List based on dynamically generated numbers in C++

Tags: c++, sorting

I have a list of objects ("Move"'s in this case) that I want to sort based on their calculated evaluation. So, I have the List, and a bunch of numbers that are "associated" with an element in the list. I now want to sort the List elements with the first element having the lowest associated number, and the last having the highest. Once the items are order I can discard the associated number. How do I do this?

This is what my code looks like (kind've):

```
list<Move> moves = board.getLegalMoves(board.turn);

for(i = moves.begin(); i != moves.end(); ++i)
{
    //...
    a = max; // <-- number associated with current Move
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would suggest a [Schwartzian transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) sort. Make a new vector (I recommend vector for more efficient sorting) of pairs of the associated value, and a pointer to its item. Sort the vector of pairs and then regenerate the list from the sorted vector. Since `operator<` is defined on a `std::pair` to be comparison by the first item of the pair and then the second, you will get a proper ordering.

Example:

```
#include <algorithm> // gives you std::sort
#include <utility>   // gives you std::pair

typedef double CostType;
typedef std::pair<CostType, Move*> Pair;

// Create the vector of pairs
std::vector<Pair> tempVec;
tempVec.reserve(moves.size());
for (std::list<Move>::iterator i = moves.begin(); i != moves.end(); ++i)
{
    CostType cost   = calcCost(*i);
    Move*    ptrToI = &(*i);
    tempVec.push_back(Pair(cost, ptrToI));
}

// Now sort 'em
std::sort(tempVec.begin(), tempVec.end());

// Regenerate your original list in sorted order by copying the original
// elements from their pointers in the Pair.
std::list<Move> sortedMoves;
for (std::vector<Pair>::iterator i = tempVec.begin(); i != tempVec.end(); ++i)
{
    sortedMoves.push_back(*(i->second));
}
```

Note that you will need a `calcCost` function that I have assumed here. This approach has an advantage over creating a comparison function if your comparison value calculation is time consuming. This way, you only pay the cost for calculating the comparison N times instead of 2 * N * log(N).

Comment: +1, sorting is much more efficient on vectors because of the RandomAccess property. And the concern for memoization is welcome indeed :)

Comment: I'd use `std::transform` instead of the last loop.

Comment: @pmr, I like std::transform as well. I would also not normally use temporary variables for `cost` and `ptrToI` in the first loop. I just thought it was more useful to spell everything out for didactic purposes.

Answer (score 4):

You could make a comparison function that compares the two elements in the way that you would like.

```
bool compare_m (const Move &first,const Move &second)
{
  if (first.thing_you_are_comparing_on() < second.thing_you_are_comparing_on()) return true;
  else return false;
}
```

Where "thing_you_are_comparing_on" is some member of the Move class that gives you the ordering you want. We use const here to make sure that we are only comparing and not  actually changing the objects in the comparison function. You can then call the sort method on the list with compare_m as the comparison function:

```
moves.sort(compare_m)
```

Something to note is that if the calculation of the comparison function is particularly expensive it may be worthwhile to precompute all the associated rank numbers before sorting.

This would require adding something to the move class to store the rank for use later:

```
class Move{
    //rest of move class

    public:
    int rank;
};

list<Move>::iterator iter;

for(iter = moves.begin(); iter != moves.end(); ++iter)
{
    //...
    (*iter).rank = max; // store the number associated with current Move
}

bool compare_rank (const Move &first,const Move &second)
{
  if (first.rank < second.rank) return true;
  else return false;
}
```

Comment: Depending on what `Move` is, you might want to pass IT PER `const Move&` instead of copying it.

Comment: This is the usual way to do it. However, I'd like to point out that it is probably much more efficient to sort in a vector than in a list. Unless, of course, your Move class is huge and copying it is prohibitively expensive.

Comment: The thing I am comparing on is not a property of Move's, though. It is just some variable. Should I add them as parameters to the compare_m function? i.e.:

    compare_m (Move first, Move second, int first, int second)

Comment: Pass Move objects by const ref, make sure that thing_are_comparing_on is ales a const method

Comment: @sbi: const is probably a good idea so I edited that in. Out of curiosity, can you think of any situation where a const in a comparison function wouldn't be beneficial?

Comment: If the thing you are comparing isn't a property of Move, it must be associated with the Move object in some way. Otherwise, you couldn't use it to sort. Make a function to look up the appropriate value for a Move, or make a list of pairs associating each Move with its value, like in my answer.

Comment: @ A. Levy, you raise a good point here about the cost associated with the comparison function, I upvoted your answer. I'm thinking if calculating the comparison function is computationally expensive then it might be better to store the results in the Move object.

Comment: @shuttle87: The reference is probably even more important than the `const`. It's just that often you can't take something by reference unless it's a `const` reference. Well, that, and that you want to indicate if a function isn't going to change its argument. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139224/2139254#2139254 for a couple of rules of thumb for how to pass function arguments.

Answer (score 0):

[`std::sort`](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/stl/algorithm/sort) is used to sort STL collections.  If the elements in the collection you are sorting can be compared simply by calling `operator<` and the collection in question is a `vector`, then sorting is very simple:

```
std::sort(collection.begin(), collection.end());
```

If the collection in question is not a `vector` but a `list` as in your case, then you can't use the general version of `std::sort`, but you can use [`std::list`](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/stl/list/sort)'s version instead:

```
list<int> numbers;
numbers.sort();
```

STL's `sort`, along with most other algorithms in the STL, come in two flavors.  One is the simple version we have already seen, which just uses `operator<` to do the comparison of two elements.  The other is a 'predicated' version, which instead of using `operator<` uses a comparison [functor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functor) you provide. This is what you need to use in your case.  There is a predicated version of `sort` for `list`, and this is what you need to use in your case.

You can create a functor in a number of ways, but one of the most useful is to derive a class from `std::unary_function` or from [`std::binary_function`](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/stl/functional/binary_function), depending on how many arguments your functor will take -- in your case, two.  Override the function-call operator,  [`operator()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kdte99aa(VS.80).aspx) and add the code that compares two elements:

```
class compare_functor : public std::binary_function<Move, Move, bool>
{
public:
  bool operator(const Move& lhs, const Move& rhs) const
  {
    int left_val = lhs.Value();
    int right_val = rhs.Value();
    return left_val < right_val;
};
```

Here is a complete working example that puts everything together.  In this program, instead of having a list of `Move`s, I have a list of 10 `string`s.  Each `string` is 6 random characters.  The list is populated by the call to [`generate_n`](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/stl/algorithm/generate_n), which uses the functor `generator` to create each random string.  Then I dump that list of strings, along with their values, by calling `copy` and passing an output iterator that dumps the values to stdout ([`ostream_iterator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wseztbaf.aspx)).  The value of each string is simply a sum of the numeric value of each character, computed by the function `strng_val`.

Then I sort the list using `list`'s predicated version of `sort`.  The comparison predicate used by `sort` is `evaluator`.  Then I finally dump the resulting list and the string values to the screen again as above:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <ctime>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

class generator 
{
public:
    generator() { srand((unsigned)time(0)); }
    string operator()() const 
    {
        string ret;
        for( int i = 0; i < 6; ++i )
            ret += static_cast<char>((rand()/(RAND_MAX/26)) + 'A');
        return ret;
    }
};

unsigned string_val(const string& rhs)
{
        unsigned val = 0;
        for( string::const_iterator it = rhs.begin(); it != rhs.end(); ++it )
            val += (*it)-'A'+1;
        return val;
};

class evaluator : public std::binary_function<string,string,bool>
{
public:
    bool operator()(const string& lhs, const string& rhs) const
    {
        return string_val(lhs) < string_val(rhs);
    }
};

class string_dumper : public std::unary_function<string, string>
{
public:
    string operator()(const string& rhs) const
    {
        stringstream ss;
        ss << rhs << " = " << string_val(rhs);
        return ss.str();
    }
};

int main() 
{
    // fill a list with strings of 6 random characters
    list<string> strings;
    generate_n(back_inserter(strings), 10, generator());
    // dump it to the screen
    cout << "Unsorted List:\n";
    transform(strings.begin(), strings.end(), ostream_iterator<string>(cout, "\n"), string_dumper());

    // sort the strings according to their numeric values computed by 'evaluator'
    strings.sort(evaluator());  // because this is a 'list', we are using list's 'sort'
    // dump it to the screen
    cout << "\n\nSorted List:\n";
    transform(strings.begin(), strings.end(), ostream_iterator<string>(cout, "\n"), string_dumper());
    return 0;

}
```